# AVFoundation: AVAudioEngine's inputNode doesn't recognize multichannel input hardware

Tags: avfoundation, ios8, beta

I have a problem with multichannel input using the new AVFoundation framework in iOS8 Beta.

I have a Focusrite Scarlett 18i8 with 18 input channels connected to my iPad Air using a lightning connector, but unfortunately the inputNode of AVAudioEngine thinks that only one channel is available from the input hardware (Cubasis App recognizes all the inputs):

```
var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
audioEngine.inputNode.numberOfInputs
```

I have made a setup, where I record the microfone input by installing a tap on the input node and it works with the build-in microphone (btw, how to debug when the lightning input is used by another device??).

Also, the output volume for a node can be adjusted by

```
inputNode.volume = 1.0
```

but how is the volume adjusted for each input channel (other that connecting each input channel to another node and adjusting the volume of these)?

I would be happy if somebody have some input on these issues. Thanks!

Comment: Please update me if there are any updates!

Answer (score 1):

A bug with id 17495735 has been submitted to Apple.